# Bixby: unable to call intent when on selection page

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have two selection `input-view` for two intent. When i am on one selection page, where i have option to choose, if i command something else, it still give me the same option selection page. Ex:

user: show me Chinese food.
Bixby: 1: Noodles 2: Sushi 3: soup
user: show me latest news
Bixby: 1: Noodles 2: Sushi 3: soup

untill and unless i am not selecting one and proceed with it, doesn't allow me to call any other intent?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `input-view` expecting to be given an input. Bixby will only move forward if this `input-view` is resolved with an input value.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:(5/24/2021)**
This was a while ago. I'm not working on Bixby now. Bixby is very dynamic and fast evolving Voice Platform.
There may be a better way to do this in latest Bixby Platform.
Please refer to the documentation and reach out to the technical support team.

**Original Answer**

I think `flag-as-off-topic` helps you out of this situation.

Check documentation @ https://www.bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/enhancing-UX.prompts

Search for `flag-as-off-topic` on this page.